# How to change the size and color of Petrel "Attributes Labels" using Ocean

Tags: ocean, petrel

I add a property to a PolylineSet using the code below (In the Petrel UI they are named “Attribute labels”)

```cs
using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    trans.Lock(polylineSet);
    PolylinePropertyCollection ppc = polylineSet.CreatePropertyCollection();
    trans.Lock(ppc);
    property = ppc.CreateProperty(PetrelProject.WellKnownTemplates.MiscellaneousGroup.General, name);
    trans.Commit();
}
```

I would like to change the size and color.
Does anyone know if this is possible via Ocean?

I want to do this because these labels have a size of 1 and color black and it isn't a good default for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't specifically altered the color and size of labels, but have dealt with size and color for polylinesets.  Maybe you can use the INumberAnnotation style object? It seems to have properties for setting font color and size.

```cs
Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Style.IStyleFactory factory = CoreSystem.GetService<Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Style.IStyleFactory>(ppc);
Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Style.INumberAnnotation style = (Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Style.INumberAnnotation)factory.GetStyle(ppc, myWindow);
if (style != null)
{
    style.FontColorType = Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Style.ColorType.White;
    style.FontSize = 400;
}
```

Hope that works.